# glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, ...) and GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_RGBA

Tags: opengl

- I have a texture array (~512 layers).
- Some of the textures I upload have 4 channels (RGBA), some have only one (RED).

When creating individual textures, I can do this:

```
GLint swizzleMask[] = { GL_ONE, GL_ONE, GL_ONE, GL_RED };
glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_RGBA, swizzleMask);
```

Can I do this for *specific* layers of my texture array? (Swizzling should apply to one texture in the array only, not the others).

I suspect this is not possible, and if so, what's the preferred method? (Vertex attributes would be my last resort option).

(i) EDIT: Looking preferably for an OpenGL 3.3 or below solution.

(ii) EDIT: The idea is that I have RGBA bitmaps for my game (grass, wall, etc...) and I also have *font* bitmaps. I'm trying to render these in the same draw call.

In my fragment shader, I have something like:

```
uniform sampler2DArray TextureArraySampler;

out vec4 FragmentColor;
in VertexOut
{
    vec2 UV;
    vec4 COLOR;
    flat uint TEXTURE_INDEX;
} In;

void main(void)
{
    FragmentColor = In.COLOR * texture(TextureArraySampler, vec3(In.UV.x, In.UV.y, In.TEXTURE_INDEX));
}
```

So, when rendering fonts, I would like the shader to sample like:

```
FragmentColor = In.COLOR * vec4(1, 1, 1, texture(TextureArraySampler, vec3(In.UV.x, In.UV.y, In.TEXTURE_INDEX)).r);
```

And, when rendering bitmaps:

```
FragmentColor = In.COLOR * texture(TextureArraySampler, vec3(In.UV.x, In.UV.y, In.TEXTURE_INDEX)).rgba;
```

Comment: @NicolBolas Updated my post :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start with, no, there's no way to do what you want. Well, there *is* a way, but it involves sticking a non-dynamically uniform conditional branch in your fragment shader, which is not a cost worth paying.

> I'm trying to render these in the same draw call.

Performance presentations around OpenGL often talk about reducing draw calls being an important aspect of performance. This is very true, particularly for high-performance applications.

*That being said*, this does not mean that one should undertake Herculean efforts to reduce the number of draw calls to 1. The point of the advice is to get people to structure their engines so that the number of draw calls does not *increase* with the complexity of the scene.

For example, consider your tile map. Issuing a draw call per-tile is bad because the number of draw calls increases linearly with the number of tiles being drawn. So it makes sense to draw the entire tile map in a single call.

Now, let's say that your scene consists of tile maps and font glyphs, and it will always be exactly that. You could rendering this in two calls (one for the maps and one for the glyphs), or you could do it in one call. But the performance difference between them will be *negligible*. What matters is that adding more tiles/glyphs does not mean adding more draw calls.

So you should not be concerned about adding a new draw call to your engine. What should concern you is if you're adding a new draw call per-X to your engine.